# modify toolbar in illustrator cs6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, plugins

I just installed the Astute Graphics plugins in AI CS6 and now my left Toolbar is too big to fit onscreen.

Is there any way I can remove/disable/hide items from it to free up space and reduce it's length?

Comment: I don't know how Astute graphics plugins would work with this, but in CC and later you can create custom tool panels: [Adobe help](http://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/custom-tools-panels.html) - [Adobe blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/jnack/2014/01/create-custom-toolbars-in-illustrator-cc.html)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe provides no method to alter the tool bar. I don't believe Astute Graphics offers any method to turn off their specific tools either. You'd need to contact the companies for tech support.